# Filtering User Changes to a Radio Button?

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to just have user input registered when changing the radio buttons on my form but obviously it triggers from program changes too which I thought I could fix by just using a boolean, this worked in a way but here is the problem:

At the moment I have two radio buttons linked and when one is triggered it triggers the other one. What is the easiest way to filter input when both methods are being called when I change a single radio button?

Comment: What do you mean of 'filter input'? It seems that you need to ignore programmatic changes, and only response to changes triggered by user.

Comment: Is there some code? Can you post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding the handlers *after* you set the value of the control:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();

  radioButton1.Checked = true;
  radioButton1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
  radioButton2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
}

private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
  if (rb.Checked)
    MessageBox.Show("User checked " + rb.Text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am changing the check boxes quite often and I don't want to un register the event handlers each time.

Comment: @JamieB Maybe I'm confused by the description *both methods are being called when I change a single radio button*.  Yes, the radio button that is being "unchecked" is also calling its `CheckChanged` event.  In which case, you can filter the "event" by just seeing if the sender is checked.  In my sample code, both radio buttons are calling that event, but only one MessageBox is getting displayed because of the `if` condition.

Comment: Ah apologies Lars, I only skimmed over the solution in reality it works fine. Thanks.